# If $a<b$ why is $a \le b$

Tags: calculus, inequality, self-learning

I recently showed a problem to someone and they stated the following:

> If $a<b$ then $a\le b$.

I find this very confusing how can if we stated that $a$ is strictly less than $b$ how can we then say that $a$ is less than $b$ and could be equal to $b$?
For example if I wanted to solve an equation where a strict inequality was stated putting $x\le b$ would be incorrect right?

Comment: Do you see that it is true that $a < b \implies a \le b$ but it is not true that $a < b \Leftarrow a \le b$? In particular, it is not true that $a < b \Leftrightarrow a \le b$

Comment: What they state is true if you consider $a \ne b$. Otherwise consider the case where $a = b$ and get your own conclusions.

Answer (score 4):

$a\le b$ is an abbreviation for $a<b\lor a=b$ ($\lor$ denoting the inclusive or, which satisfies $p\implies(p\lor q)$).

Comment: But if I had an equation say $x+2<4$ then surely I cannot say x+2$\le$4 and then solve the equation giving x$\le$4

Comment: Sorry that should be x$\le$2

Comment: @Thehomeschooler I think you're referring to the fact that $\{x|x\le2\}\ne\{x|x<2\}$. This isn't an issue with inequalities so much as the fact that, when you determine which $x$ satisfy a condition, any unidirectional inference may introduce spurious solutions you remove by checking them later.

Comment: So it is not incorrect to say this

Comment: also what do you mean by satisfies $p$ $\implies $ (p$\lor$q)

Comment: @Thehomeschooler I mean for ay true $p$ and for any proposition $q$, $p\lor q$ is also true. BTW, I advise you to just put one pair of dollar signs around the entire expression.

Answer (score 0):

Define $\leq$ first say on the set of integers:

$a\leq b :\Leftrightarrow \exists c\in\Bbb Z_{\geq 0}:\; a+ c =b$.

Then define $<$ as follows

$a<b :\Leftrightarrow a\leq b \wedge a\ne b.$

Comment: So, for every two integers $a,b$, one has $a \leq b$?

Comment: The set is totally ordered, so $a\leq b$ or $b\leq a$.

Comment: Yeah, but according to your definition, one could take $c = -1$.

Comment: Right, I wanted to define it first for the nat. numbers. I'll change it.